# GeoServer provide WMS without authentication

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms, geonode

I'm trying to understand how can add a layer from my GeoServer without have to basic authenticate.

The problem is when in QGIS I try to add a WMS layer and I put as URL as `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/my_ws/wms?` If I do that it doesn't show anything. I've noticed that my workspace(my_ws) requires a basic authentication (username and password). If I preview any layer of my workspace it works fine, and I don't need any identification.

I'm using GeoNode and for that, GeoNode has a authprovider. My default is Basic authentication username/password.

How can I add a WMS layer to QGIS without authentication?

Comment: turn off authentication for your workspace

Comment: yes, but how can i do that?

Comment: By default it is off. Have you been experimenting with authentication of do you have services which you want to require authentication?

Comment: I'm using geonode and for that, geonode has  a authprovider.my default is Basic authentication username/password

Comment: geonode authentication is handled by django which is independent to geoserver. It works for me without any authentication.

Comment: remove my_ws. a working example is http://master.demo.geonode.org/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities